# One bullet killed our beloved president. One bullet, but not one man

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

According to the movie: The Conspirator (2010)

It mentioned this phrase:

> One bullet killed our beloved president. One bullet, but not one man

President is a man. Kill president means kill a man. but the phrase says: kill president, but no man? What is the phrase trying to say?

Comment: The claim being made is that more than one person was involved in the conspiracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "[one bullet, one man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-bullet_theory)" theory is that the assassination involved only one shooter who fired a single bullet that wound up injuring 3 people: President Kennedy, Governor Conally, and a bystander.

Different conspiracy theories vary by the number of people involved and the number of bullets shot. Some theories claim there were multiple shooters, some claim Lee Harvey Oswald shot twice, some claim that Oswald was framed and wasn't involved at all.

> One bullet killed our beloved president. One bullet, but not one man

This theory claims that Oswald only shot a single bullet but that he didn't act alone. Others were perhaps involved in the planning or something. One bullet did all the damage, but there was more than one man involved.